# How do I get Timestamp properties to be rendered when I use EditorForModel()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic-data, razor, data-annotations

I have the following domain entity decorated with System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations:

```
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]        
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }        

    [Timestamp]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=true)]
    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
```

When I render my model in the view using `@Html.EditorForModel()` nothing is rendered for the version property. Is there anything that can force `EditorForModel()` method to render the `byte[]`?

PS: Using `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Version)` works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You could also create an EditorTemplate named Version and design the output how you see fit.  add a UIHint attribute to version in order to use it.

Comment: When I create a custom editor template for the version property it still doesn't show up when i use EditorForModel. It will show up when I use EditorFor(x => x.Version) explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

A `byte[]` is considered to be a complex type by the `EditorForModel` method and there currently is no way for those to be displayed. You could try adding another property to your model (typed as `string` for example) that would read from and write to your `Version` property.

Answer (score 1):

Better write your own template (Object.ascx). 
Copy the standard MVC Object.ascx template and change the ShouldShow Method to:

```
 public static bool ShouldShow(ModelMetadata metadata, ViewDataDictionary viewData) {
      return metadata.ShowForDisplay
      && metadata.ModelType != typeof(System.Data.EntityState)
      && (!metadata.IsComplexType || metadata.ModelType == typeof(System.Byte[]))
      && !viewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(metadata);
  }
```